# App Store release version of app crashes

Tags: ios, app-store

I've just released my first app on the app store (https://appsto.re/au/XLgKeb.i) and it crashes on launch.  I've narrowed it down to being something to do with a network connection the app makes on launch, maybe with the iTunes store for in app purchase information...
But the weird thing is that it was fine in the xcode simulator, it was fine through the testflight beta test, it even worked for the app store review person.  Why is this happening all of the sudden?  Also, what is the best way to debug this as I feel like it is going to be very hard without the console...  I also don't know how I will know if its fixed, as I feel like I would have to submit it to apple and get it approved for me to test if it still crashes on the app store version?

Ruins the excitement of releasing my first app...

Thank you.

EDIT: Here is a symbolicated crash log from my own phone after the crash. I'm struggling to decipher it... http://pastebin.com/PT2xEjd9
When the app launches it calls this function.

```
func requestProduct() {
    DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
        IAPProducts.store.requestProducts{success, products in
            if success {
                self.product = products?[0]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Something goes wrong with the in app purchase request...
Here is the whole class for reference: http://pastebin.com/tE410hWP

Comment: Can you see anything under "crashes" in the Xcode organiser?

Comment: No crash information available @Paulw11
It has only been up for an hour and the crashes have happened within the last 30 minutes, if it takes a while for them to come through?

Comment: Yes, you will need to wait for crashes to be collected.  Without a crash you are just guessing.

Comment: @Paulw11 Here is a log from my own phone that I found after the crash: http://pastebin.com/GqPMYTgF, it doesn't seem to help me much? I'm not used to these different types of crash logs.

Comment: You need to symbolicate the crash log and then update your question with relevant code, the relevant portion of the stack trace, and point out the exact line causing the crash.

Comment: You have not posted a symbolicated crash log.

Comment: That is part of the log I get when I use the "re-symbolicate log" option on the crash log in my devices crash list in xcode.  I was under the impression that xcode symbolicated the log? I'm not sure what I'm doing. 

I do now know that my app is working for people, apple mustn't have been returning the in app purchase at some point, so it was throwing an error somewhere that I wasn't handling. I'll read up on symbolicating to see if I can figure this out. @rmaddy

Comment: What I posted must be the symbolicated crash log? http://pastebin.com/czJ8RL1E
I even did it manually with the symbolicatecrash unix executable and it spit out the same results. @rmaddy

Comment: A symbolicated log shows method names, file names, and line numbers.

Comment: My bad, figured out I needed to download dSYM files from itunes connect. Updated the crash log on the question @rmaddy

Comment: Intersting. Your app was crashing for me on my work wifi but it works on 4g.

Comment: The crash seems to be in an array access in your product request completionhandler closure which is in your view controller. Please add that code

Comment: @Paulw11 the code where I retrieve the product array is in the entire IAPManager.swift class I posted in the question.  The snippet of code where I request the products from the ViewController is also posted in the question.  It is supposed to be storing the only product, thus the [0], in an optional SKProduct variable as you can see...

Comment: Ok. You should make that code safer. It will crash in the event of an empty array; `products` may not be nil, but `products[0]` will give an array bounds error. Conditionally unwrapping `products?.first` will avoid this problem

Comment: Right, so I've changed "self.product = products?[0]" to "self.product = products?.first", that should fix the problem?  I guess that makes sense!  I was just assuming that "products?[0]" would return nil.  Thanks for your help!